How does the Yamato yo, Towa ni: Rebel 3199 movie relate to the original 1974 Space Battleship Yamato?
Some years ago, I watched the classic 1974 Space Battleship Yamato. Now I've found a movie called Yamato yo, Towa ni: Rebel 3199.
How does the Yamato yo, Towa ni: Rebel 3199 movie, relate to the original 1974 Space Battleship Yamato?

According to the Yamato 2205 remakes' lead writer, Fukui Harutoshi, Be Forever
Yamato: Rebel 3199 is intended to be a remake that mixes elements from the original Be Forever Yamato (2202, in the original series timeline) and Space Battleship Yamato III (early 2203, in the original series timeline)

So a sequel to the original 70's series I guess?

Yes. Yamato III is the third season of the TV show, Be Forever Yamato is a movie that precedes it. Both are from 1980.
